# NULL result without error in PyObject_Call

Tags: python, c, null

I'm currently coding a Python C-Extension to perform some calculations in C instead of Python. It works just fine, I already got some nice results, but the point is, I get the following error:

```
NULL result without error in PyObject_Call
```

It occurs sometimes, not always, when I want to create an instance of the "C Python Object" I created. The call looks something like the following:

```
import c_class

obj = c_class.dummy(arg1, arg2, arg3);
```

Does anyone have any suggestions? I don't know where this error comes from, since it works from time to time.. I'm kind of lost here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you return `NULL` from a c function exposed to python you must set the error message before, since returning `NULL` means an error happened.

If an error happened and you are returning `NULL` because of that then, use [`PyErr_SetString()`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/exceptions.html), if no error happened, then use

```
Py_RETURN_NONE;
```

Comment: I don't think an error happened.. that's what's puzzling me. Anyway: how would I use that PyErr_SetString() function?

Comment: Is the c function yours? did you return `NULL` from it, it's you who decides if an error happened. Why is the function returning `NULL`, can you post it's code?

Comment: yeah, it's my function. It's a void function though, doesn't it mean I don't have to return anything?

Comment: As a matter of fact, it seems to work now. I'll be in touch if I stumble upon it again. Thanks a lot.